# PKCS 10 mime data handler for Bouncy castle

Tags: bouncycastle

What data handler API should be used for PKCS 8 or 10/12 certs? For PKCS7,  I add these to activation layer's MailcapCommandMap.

`"application/pkcs7-mime;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_mime")`

`"application/x-pkcs7-signature;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.x_pkcs7_signature")`

In [javadoc of BC](https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bcjmail-jdk18on/1.72/index.html?org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/handlers/x_pkcs7_signature.html), could see mime, signature handlers for pkcs7, but not for higher variants.